# Create Smart Tag for control

Tags: c#, user-controls, design-time, designtime-attributes

Can I add "Smart Tag" feature to all controls existing on the Form that derived from "Control" class, where this control doesn't have this feature originally. 
This "Smart Tag" may contains an editor for any property of this control. And I want it done using new component, so when I drop it on the form all controls on the form will use my own designer including their originally one.

For example:
when drop TextBox control on the form a small triangle appears on the top of the control (The "Smart Tag")and when you click it, a new list drop down which contains (Check box for MultiLine property), what I need is when drop my component, this component will give (or inject the designer) to the button, for example or any other control, a feature like that or add new property to its exiting "Smart Tag", so if I want to include "Name" property to control's smart tag, the button control will have this new feature on its designer and the TextBox control has its new property injected into its originally Smart Tag list

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need WPF and its attached properties.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I need it in windows form 
for example if I have a component that implement IExtenderProvider interface so the defined ProvideProperty should be attached to the component (where can extend) smart tag.